# Private class variables won't change when function is called

Tags: c++

I have problem when i try to change my 2 private class variables in FBullCowGame.h .It seems like constructor is calling function Reset() [Located in FBullCowGame.cpp] but Reset() function wont change integers MyMaxTries & MyCurrentTry.I'm new to c++ so probably it's something obvious but i can't find it .

This is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FBullCowGame.h"

using FText = std::string;

void PrintIntro();
void PlayGame();

FText GetGuess();
FText PrintGuess();

FBullCowGame BCGame;//Dodeljujemo naziv u main-u FBullCowGame-u , takodje ako ima neki kod u constructoru on ga izvrsava pri ovaj deklaraciji


bool AskToPlayAgain();


int main() 
{

    bool bPlayAgain = false;
    do {
        PrintIntro();
        PlayGame();
        bPlayAgain = AskToPlayAgain();
        }
    while (bPlayAgain);

        return 0;
}

void PrintIntro()
{
    //Define constant var
    constexpr int WORD_LENGHT = 6;

    //Welcome to the player and asking the guess
    std::cout << "Welcome to Bulls and Cows\n";
    std::cout << "Can you guess my " << WORD_LENGHT;
    std::cout << " letter isogram word?\n";
}

void PlayGame()
{
    BCGame.Reset();
    int MaxTries = BCGame.GetMaxTries();
    //Looping for guesses
    for (int i = 1; i <= MaxTries; i++)
    {
        FText Guess = GetGuess();
        //Repeat the guess back to them
        std::cout << "Your guess is: " << Guess << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}

FText GetGuess()
{
    int CurrentTry = BCGame.GetCurrentTry();

    //Player enters their guess
    std::cout << std::endl << "Try " << CurrentTry << ".What is your guess?\n";
    FText Guess = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, Guess);

    return Guess;
}

bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    FText Response = "";
    std::cout << "Do you want to play again (y/n) ?" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);

    return (Response[0] == 'y') || (Response[0] == 'Y');


}
```

FBullCowGame.h /

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class FBullCowGame {
public:
    FBullCowGame();//Constructor izvrsava se kod u njemu pri deklaraciji BCGame u nasem slucaju


    int GetMaxTries() const;
    int GetCurrentTry()const;
    bool IsGameWon()const;

    void Reset();
    bool CheckGuessValidity(std::string);



private:
    //Compile time values gets overwritten by run time values in Constructor
    int MyMaxTries;
    int MyCurrentTry;



};
```

And FBullCowGame.cpp /

```
#include "FBullCowGame.h"

FBullCowGame::FBullCowGame()
{
    //Run time values
    Reset();
}

void FBullCowGame::Reset()
{

    constexpr int MAX_TRIES = 8;
    int MyMaxTries = MAX_TRIES;
    int MyCurrentTry = 1;

    return;
}

int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries ()const
{
    return MyMaxTries;
}

int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry ()const
{

    return MyCurrentTry;
}

bool FBullCowGame::IsGameWon ()const
{
    return false;
}

bool FBullCowGame::CheckGuessValidity(std::string)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are redeclaring your variables within `Reset`: `int MyMaxTries = MAX_TRIES;
    int MyCurrentTry = 1;` Remove the `int` to avoid redeclaration. Voting to close as typographical error.

Comment: In Reset, you're creating a new variable, not resetting the old one. Don't constantly redeclare variables.

Comment: Remove `int` when referring to the variables you want to change inside the `Reset()` method. What you are experiencing is called `shadowing`.

Comment: Present a [MCVE] that you get from your debugging activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing your member variables with function-local variables that happen to have the exact same name.

```
void FBullCowGame::Reset()
{

    constexpr int MAX_TRIES = 8;
    int MyMaxTries = MAX_TRIES;
    int MyCurrentTry = 1;

    return;
}
```

Just assign to your member variables, but don't redeclare them

```
void FBullCowGame::Reset()
{    
    constexpr int MAX_TRIES = 8;
    MyMaxTries = MAX_TRIES;
    MyCurrentTry = 1;
}
```